# Xamarin Forms: limit the length of an entry that is data bound

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, attachedbehaviors

I am trying to use a behavior to limit the length of an entry field that is also data bound, and I can't figure it out. Data binding works when I don't use the behavior. Using the behavior to limit the entry length works, but it breaks the data binding. Here's my code:

in XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
    x:Class="MyApp.UserInfoPage"  
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyApp.Behaviors">
    ...  
        <Entry x:Name="UserName" FontSize="Small" Keyboard="Text">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior MaxLength="7"/>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
    ...
```

in XAML.cs:

```
public MyInfoPage(MyDataAdapter myDataAdapter)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = myDataAdapter;
    UserName.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "UserName", BindingMode.TwoWay);
...
```

and EntryLengthValidatorBehavior.cs:

```
class EntryLengthValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entry = (Entry)sender;

        if (entry.Text != null && entry.Text.Length > this.MaxLength)
        {
            string entryText = entry.Text;
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
            entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. The only difference I have is that I put the binding in XAML instead of in the page constructor but it also works if I change that to your way. How did you verify that your binding didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either something was going on in my debug session, or I had a brain fart, because everything works as expected after re-starting Visual Studio. Sorry for the confusion.